# Why does the new address from realloc not get reflected outside the function?

Tags: c, realloc

I have marked here four printf statements. My problem is that upon finishing my function AddSub where a reallocation takes place, the address contained by struct sub *temp which is supposedly to be assigned to struct sub *a, does not get reflected when the program gets back to function main where I print the address of struct sub *dstore.

The first, second and third printf statements show that the reallocation was successful (printf 2 shows temp received a new address, print 3 shows the address was assigned to a). But I'm very confused on why the fourth printf shows otherwise.

```
struct sub {
  char code[8];
  float units;
  char tag[101];
};

void AddSub(struct sub *a, struct cla *b, int *ctr){
  char ecode[8], etags[101];
  float eunits;
  struct sub *temp = a;

  scanf("%s %f %s", ecode, &eunits, etags);

  if (!(AlIn(ecode) + UnCh(ecode, a, *ctr)))
  {
    if(*ctr)
    {
      printf("Before realloc: %p, %p\n", (void*)a, (void*)temp); /*1st*/
      temp = realloc(a, (*ctr + 1) * sizeof(*a));               
      printf("After realloc: %p, %p\n", (void*)a, (void*)temp); /*2nd*/     
    }

    if(!temp)
    {
      printf("Insufficient space.\n");
      free(a); free(b);
      exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
      if(*ctr)
      {
        a = temp;               
        printf("After AddSub readdress: %p, %p\n", (void*)a, (void*)temp); /*3rd*/
      }

      strcpy((a + *ctr) -> code, ecode);
      (a + *ctr) -> units = eunits;
      strcpy((a + *ctr) -> tag, etags); 

      printf("%s saved. ", (a + *ctr) -> code);
      *ctr = *ctr + 1;
    }
  }     
}

int main()
{
  char com[14];
  int subctr = 0, clactr = 0;
  struct sub *dstore;
  struct cla *cstore;
  if (!(dstore = malloc(sizeof(struct sub))))
    exit(1);
  if (!(cstore = malloc(sizeof(struct cla))))
  {
    free(datastore);
    exit(1);
  }

  while(1)
  {
    printf("INPUT> ");
    scanf("%s", com);

    if(strcmp(com, "ADD-SUBJECT") == 0)
    {
        AddSub(dstore, cstore, &subctr);
        printf("Finished Addsub: %p\n", dstore);  /*4th*/
    }
    else if (strcmp(com, "EXIT") == 0)
    {
        printf("Bye!\n");
        free(dstore); free(cstore); 
        return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("What?.\n");     
  }
}
```

Comment: Because in C, function parameters are passed by value (they are copied). If you assign to a parameter inside the function, it will only affect the copy local to the function, and not the original parameter in the caller itself.

Answer (score 1):

C uses pass by value. When you have, for example:

```
void func(int a)
{
    a = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 6;
    func(b);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

the output is `6`. This small example is essentially what is happening in your code, with `5` replaced by `realloc`, and `int` replaced by a pointer type.

In order to set a variable in a function and have those changes be visible outside the function, you either need to pass the variable by reference, or return the variable.

Comment: "pass by reference" means the technique of allowing the called function to refer to the variable in the calling function. [See here for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring

```
void AddSub(struct sub *a, struct cla *b, int *ctr)
```

using

```
 a
```

and passing

```
   AddSub(dstore, cstore, &subctr);
```

declare

```
   void AddSub(struct sub **a, struct cla **b, int *ctr)
```

use

```
   *a
```

and pass

```
  AddSub(&dstore, &cstore, &subctr);
```

same as you already did with `subctr`.